# unserialize array

Tags: php, serialization

I am return a serialize array from a post meta field in wordpress called groups.

here is how it looks in to post meta field.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

how can i loop trough this and run an if statement i.e.

```
$mydata = unserialize($meta['groups']);

print_r($mydata);
```

The unserialzed isnt working for me the ouput i get from the print_r is below

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

which is same as above.

Any help on working with serialized and unserialzed arrays never used before.

Comment: It is working fine look at this http://codepad.org/v7dWWpPn

Comment: That's not your real code or your real input data then.

Answer (score 1):

Propably [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is active. Strip the slashes generated by it with [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$mydata = unserialize(stripslashes($meta['groups']));
```

If you want to strip slashes from the whole GPC-Array use this (Credits go to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php#99183) comment on PHP.net):

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $strip_slashes_deep = function ($value) use (&$strip_slashes_deep) {
          return is_array($value) ? array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $value) : stripslashes($value);
      };
      $_GET = array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $_GET);
      $_POST = array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $_POST);
      $_COOKIE = array_map($strip_slashes_deep, $_COOKIE);
  }
```

Comment: Note that `array_map` isn't recursive. You'd probably be better off with `array_walk_recursive`.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen Note that I map it to a recursive function.

Comment: I was a little too fast there it seems. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I obtained using command-line PHP:

```
php > $x = unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}');
php > print_r($x);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

It seems that `$meta['groups']` does not contain the serialized string.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}'));
```

will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

The unserialization works just fine. How do you know if `$meta['groups']` contains what you want?