# how to parse the following string to json in php

Tags: php, json, yii, yii2

I need small as `key` and `url` as value for example :-

> small->upload\2016\04\greenfield-100x100.jpg

```
"a:3:{s:5:\"small\";s:39:\"\/uploads\/2016\/04\/greenfield-100x100.jpg\";s:6:\"medium\";s:39:\"\/uploads\/2016\/04\/greenfield-300x200.jpg\";s:5:\"large\";s:39:\"\/uploads\/2016\/04\/greenfield-500x400.jpg\";}""
```

Comment: You have a serialized string here. You can decode with `unserialize()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unserialize array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141034/unserialize-array)

Comment: Please read the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: ok thanks sorry new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `unserialize` for getting the data as Readable / Understandable. Your data is valid.

> [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) takes a single serialized variable and converts it back
>   into a PHP value.

```
$data = "a:3:{s:5:\"small\";s:39:\"/uploads/2016/04/greenfield-100x100.jpg\";s:6:\"medium\";s:39:\"/uploads/2016/04/greenfield-300x200.jpg\";s:5:\"large\";s:39:\"/uploads/2016/04/greenfield-500x400.jpg\";}";
$out = unserialize($data);
print_r($out);
```

The Result after `unserialize`.

```
Array
(
    [small] => /uploads/2016/04/greenfield-100x100.jpg
    [medium] => /uploads/2016/04/greenfield-300x200.jpg
    [large] => /uploads/2016/04/greenfield-500x400.jpg
)
```